# Combining two images on one canvas in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working with the HTML5 canvas element. Let's say I have 2 ImageData objects that I want to combine to be able to put on one canvas. Lets assume that I don't care how these images combine. Both ImageData objects have the exact same pixel count and shape.

What's the best way to combine the two images?

I figure that I can write a for loop and iterate over the ImageData array and manually combine and set every rgba value per pixel, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?  I need this operation to happen as quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "combine" mean? You want one dropped over the other so you can't see it? You want one superimposed on top of the other? You want them stacked end-to-end?

Comment: I want to drop one on top of the other.  Most of the pixels in these images are completely transparent.  So if image1 has a black circle on the left half of it, and image2 has a square on the right half of it, I'd like to combine them so I get 1 image with a circle on the left and a square on the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're simply looking to superimpose one image on top of another, you probably want to do something like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(image1, x, y);
// adjust globalAlpha as needed, or skip if the image has its own transparency
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.drawImage(image2, x, y);
```

OR, depending on the specific effect you're after:

```
ctx.drawImage(image1, x, y);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten"; // many other possibilities here
ctx.drawImage(image2, x, y);
```

This will probably be faster than drawing pixel-by-pixel through the get/putImageData methods, though by how much is browser-dependent.

Comment: The questioner said (in a later comment) that the image pixels are mostly transparent, so I don't think the alpha or compositing operation even need to be set.

Comment: That's correct. I'll update the comment in the first set of code.