# multiple images in canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to display a few images which will be one on top of the other in some parallel areas.
What is the right way to do it if each image should be rotated in a different angle and located in different coordinates (x,y)?

Do I need to draw them on a single canvas and somehow rotate them differently in that canvas, or should I create different canvas for each image?
once I created different canvas for each image, it displayed only the last image and the canvases were one next to the other with no parallel areas..

Thanks...

Comment: Nothing here you can use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878319/combining-two-images-on-one-canvas-in-html5

Comment: A visual example of what you want would help.

Comment: would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

canvas has those very useful transforms that you can use.
What you need right now is canvas' `.translate` and `.rotate`

Let's say you make a function which takes an `img` image, `x` coordinate, `y` coordinate and `rad` rotation to your top left corner argument, this is how you'd do it:

```
function displayRotatedImage( img, x, y, rad ){

    ctx.translate( x, y ); // ctx is your canvas context
    ctx.rotate( rad );
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    ctx.rotate( -rad ); // don't forget to get everything to its previous state!
    ctx.translate( -x, -y );


}
```

Do you see what's going on? first of all we move to the pivot of the rotation using `.translate`, then we rotate around that pivot using `.rotate`, and we draw our image relatively to our system, and since 0 0 is our pivot point now, thanks to the translate, we simply draw the image at 0 0. Now we have to derotate and detranslate to get the canvas to it's original transform ;)